# Duda existencial en query de base de datos SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```sql
select
    c.nombre,
    c.nomenclatura,
    u.nombre,
    u.id_perfil
from
    clientes c
    left join clientes_usuario cu on c.id_cliente = cu.id_cliente
    left join usuarios u on u.id_usuario = cu.id_usuario
where c.estatus = 1
order by c.nombre asc
```

Me arroja lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera solo obtener y agrupar aquellos registros que no tengan asociado algún registro con `id_perfil` 16, el resultado debe ser el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Elimina las etiquetas que no corresponden: ¿qué relación tiene _oracle_ o _jquery_ con la pregunta? Además, especifica en el título el problema en particular: _duda existencial con.._. no da pistas del problema. Y por último, evita lo más posible adjuntar imágenes, ya que no todos pueden visualizarlas. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Lo que dices que buscas y lo que tachas en las imágenes no corresponde. Tu pregunta es entonces, un ejercicio de adivinación.

Comment: Hola Gold, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles y marcar como aceptada la que resolvio tu problema, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    c.nombre,
    c.nomenclatura,
    u.nombre,
    u.id_perfil
from
    clientes c
    left join clientes_usuario cu on c.id_cliente = cu.id_cliente
    left join usuarios u on u.id_usuario = cu.id_usuario
where c.estatus = 1  
and c.nomenclatura not in 
(
 select
 c.nomenclatura,
 from
 clientes c
 left join clientes_usuario cu on c.id_cliente = cu.id_cliente
 left join usuarios u on u.id_usuario = cu.id_usuario
 where c.estatus = 1 and c.id_perfil = 16
)
order by c.nombre asc
```

Tu consulta original se mantiene, pero agregarías una subconsulta la cual seleccionará solamente el **campo nomenclatura** de los registros cuyo **campo id_perfil** sea **16**. Posteriormente en tu consulta original utilizarías el **operador not in** para filtrar los registros de la consulta original cuyo **campo
nomenclatura** tenga un valor que no esté en los registros devueltos en tu subconsulta.

Answer (score -1):

El texto y las filas tachadas de la captura generan confusión.

Si lo que buscas es no mostrar las filas cuyo `u.id_perfil` no sea 16, la sugerencia de @masterguru me parece correcta. Ahora, teniendo en cuenta la imagen, si lo que buscas es filtrar las filas que tengan ***cualquier*** valor en esa columna, el filtro cambia.

```sql
select
    c.nombre,
    c.nomenclatura,
    u.nombre,
    u.id_perfil
from
    clientes c
    left join clientes_usuario cu on c.id_cliente = cu.id_cliente
    left join usuarios u on u.id_usuario = cu.id_usuario
where c.estatus = 1
and u.id_perfil = NULL
order by c.nombre asc
```

Asumiendo que el valor de `u.id_perfil` sea `NULL` cuando la fila no tiene ningún valor asociado.